# flask-security does not hash the new created password, but update it hashed when login the first time

Tags: flask, flask-security

I'm new to flask-security. I have already set `app.config["SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT"] = "something"`. Every time I create user by

```
    user_datastore.create_user(
        email=username,
        password=password,
        roles=["level 1"])
    db_session.commit()
```

The creation is fine, but the password of this new user in the database is not hashed. However, when I login by the `login_view`, the password in the database updates the hashed.

1. Why does the login process update the password?
2. Am I missing some settings for making the password hashed at the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states (in 3.4.x) - when using create_user - it stores whatever you pass it! This is noted as a really really bad thing - you must hash it (example given in API docs for create_user).

By default - the configuration variable: SECURITY_DEPRECATED_PASSWORD_SCHEMES defines schemes that are views 'bad' - and if encountered - will automatically be re-hashed on login. This allows the user database to be slowly updated when older crypto is deemed inadequate.